# Is there a Python equivalent to the PHP function htmlspecialchars()?

Tags: php, python, html-entities, htmlspecialchars

Is there a similar or equivalent function in Python to the PHP function htmlspecialchars()? The closest thing I've found so far is htmlentitydefs.entitydefs().

Comment: It seems that there is more than one obvious way to do it! O noes!

Answer (score 12):

Closest thing I know about is [cgi.escape](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape).

Comment: it was deprecated since 3.3

Answer (score 7):

```
from django.utils.html import escape
print escape('<div class="q">Q & A</div>')
```

Comment: I'm voting for this because I don't want to parse anything like some of the other answers, or even do a search and replace, I want a single function that does it all for me.

Answer (score 5):

Building on @garlon4 answer, you can define your own `htmlspecialchars(s)`:

```
def htmlspecialchars(text):
    return (
        text.replace("&", "&amp;").
        replace('"', "&quot;").
        replace("<", "&lt;").
        replace(">", "&gt;")
    )
```

Comment: I think python has a fancy function named something like "translate" that you could use to make this even shorter

Comment: Too lazy right now but yeah: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/translate

Comment: Helpful answer, however you're passing the parameters to replace() in the wrong order.
Should be: replace("string to find", "string to replace")

Comment: @Ben no, the function works as expected (it escapes the "html special chars"). It looks for the char to escape, and replaces it by the html escape sequence for that char. Maybe you wanted to un-escape instead?

Comment: My mistake! @AlejandroVD you are spot on.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [xml.sax.saxutils.escape](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.escape):

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
escape(unsafe, {'"':'&quot;'}) # ENT_COMPAT
escape(unsafe, {'"':'&quot;', '\'':'&#039;'}) # ENT_QUOTES
escape(unsafe) # ENT_NOQUOTES
```

Have a look at [xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.utils.html#xml.sax.saxutils.quoteattr), it might be more useful for you

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest way is just to use replace:

```
text.replace("&", "&amp;").replace('"', "&quot;").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;")
```

PHP only escapes those four entities with htmlspecialchars.  Note that if you have ENT_QUOTES set in PHP, you need to replace quotes with &#039; rather than &quot;.

Answer (score 1):

The `html.entities` module (`htmlentitydefs` for python 2.x) contains a dictionary `codepoint2name` which should do what you need.

```
>>> import html.entities
>>> html.entities.codepoint2name[ord("&")]
'amp'
>>> html.entities.codepoint2name[ord('"')]
'quot'
```

Answer (score 1):

Only five characters need to be escaped, so you can use a simple one-line function:

```
def htmlspecialchars(content):
    return content.replace("&", "&amp;").replace('"', "&quot;").replace("'", "&#039;").replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using django 1.0 then your template variables will already be encoded and ready for display. You also use the  `safe` operator `{{ var|safe }}` if you don't want it globally turned on.