# Python encode string to html

Tags: python, html, string, encode

How would one take a string and encode special characters to html?

for example, if I have "test@test" how would I encode it so it becomes "test%40test"

Is there an easy way of doing this instead of using replace to manually list every one I want to replace?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931423/is-there-a-python-equivalent-to-the-php-function-htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `urlencode`function. Documentation here.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode